# How to single out the first parameter sent to a macro taking only a variadic parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I try to get at the first actual parameter sent to a variadic macro. This is what I tried, and which does not work in VS2010:

```
#define FIRST_ARG(N, ...) N
#define MY_MACRO(...) decltype(FIRST_ARG(__VA_ARGS__))
```

When I look at the preprocessor output I see that `FIRST_ARG` returns the entire argument list sent to `MY_MACRO`...

On the other hand when I try with:

```
FIRST_ARG(1,2,3)
```

it expands to 1 as intended.

This seems to be somehow the inverse of the problem solved by the infamous two level concat macros. I know that "macro parameters are fully expanded before inserted in the macro body" but this does not seem to help me here as I don't understand what this means in the context of ... and `__VA_ARGS__`

Obviously `__VA_ARGS__` binds to `N` and is only evaluated later. I tried several ways with extra macro levels but it didn't help.

Answer (score 11):

This is [a bug in the Visual C++ preprocessor](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/380090/variadic-macro-replacement).  The workaround listed there works.  This:

```
#define FIRST_ARG_(N, ...) N
#define FIRST_ARG(args) FIRST_ARG_ args
#define MY_MACRO(...) decltype(FIRST_ARG((__VA_ARGS__)))

MY_MACRO(x, y, z)
```

expands to:

```
decltype(x)
```

Comment: I note that link has a "workaround" which looks potentially helpful.

Comment: @aschepler: Yes; I was just looking at that and testing it with the OP's use case. It works just fine and I've added a demonstration to the answer.  The workaround also demonstrates the overarching rule when writing macros:  "if at first you don't succeed, add more parentheses." ;-)

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly/5134656#5134656)

Comment: gee VS... always the better surprise compiler :'(