# two layers call for __VA_ARGS__ in VS 2008 failed

Tags: c++, macros, variadic

I use **VA_ARGS**  for the following case:

```
#define CHECK4(x,y,...) if ((x)) { y(__VA_ARGS__); }
#define CHECK5(x,y,...) if ((x)) { y(__VA_ARGS__); }
```

Then call it:

```
CHECK5(1, CHECK4,1,printf, "here %s %s %s", "are", "some", "varargs2(4)\n");
```

In vs 2008, it failed for CHECK5 calling, but using gcc it works well.
How should I let it work in VS 2008?

Comment: This might be a duplicate; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5134523/420683) and try to use the workaround described there.

Answer (score 1):

```
CHECK5(1, CHECK4(1,printf, "here %s %s %s", "are", "some", "varargs2(4)\n"), 1);
```