# __VA_ARGS__ expansion using MSVC

Tags: c, visual-c++, macros, variadic-macros

I found a question showing how to overload macros based on the number of arguments :
[Overloading Macro on Number of Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments)

But as they say, it's not working using MSVC because MSVC expands `__VA_ARGS__` into a single token instead of a list of arguments (`arg1, arg2, arg3`).

They point to another question where a work around is given : [MSVC doesn't expand __VA_ARGS__ correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly)
But not explained at all, so I can't adapt it to my own case since I can't understand it.

Could you please explain how this workaround works ?

Comment: I think the linked post is not correct. I think the right solution is `G(...)  F(EXPAND(__VA_ARGS__) )`

Comment: @LPs, I thought so too, but try it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm too Linux inside to put my hands on MSVC :). Seriously, I haven't got MSVC to test it. Let  OP try it

Comment: No, try your version on Linux.  Gcc throws an error.

Comment: Thanks but that's still not explaining the logic behind this workaround.

Comment: @JohnBollinger probably I'm very stupid, but how I can define VA_ARGS to compile that code?

Comment: @LPs, you do not need to define `VA_ARGS`.  Just run the preprocessor on given text: `gcc -E demo.h`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you. Today is a good day: I learned something new..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The workaround in question is this:

```
#define EXPAND( x ) x
#define F(x, ...) X = x and VA_ARGS = __VA_ARGS__
#define G(...) EXPAND( F(__VA_ARGS__) )
```

The idea is that given an existing variadic macro `F()`:

```
#define F(x, ...) X = x and VA_ARGS = __VA_ARGS__
```

instead of writing your desired variadic wrapper macro as, in this case, ...

```
#define G(...) F(__VA_ARGS__)
```

... you write `G()` with use of the additional `EXPAND()` macro.  The actual definition of `F()` is not the point, and in particular it doesn't matter for this example that macro expansion does not produce valid C code.  Its purpose is to demonstrate the preprocessor's behavior with respect to macro arguments.  Specifically, it shows that although MSVC expands `__VA_ARGS__` to a single token in a variadic macro, that can be worked around by forcing a double expansion.

For example, using the workaround definition, the preprocessor first expands ...

```
G(1, 2, 3)
```

... to ...

```
EXPAND( F(1, 2, 3) )
```

... where the `1, 2, 3` is treated as a single token.  That tokenization no longer matters when the preprocessor rescans for additional replacements, however: it sees the `1`, `2`, `3` as separate arguments to macro `F()`, and expands that as desired to produce the argument to macro `EXPAND()`, which just replaces it with itself.

If you think it odd that this works as intended, but the version without `EXPAND()` does not work (in MSVC), you are right.

Comment: It works, thanks. I also understand it better now. Calling the macro where the arguments are supposed to be expanded using another macro causes the compiler to expand the arguments correctly.

Comment: Actually my case is little bit different. I would like to overload based on the number of arguments : 1 arg -> method for 1 arg, 2 args -> method for 2 args. BUT : I would also like that >2 args -> method for 2 args + va args, since the two overloads for my macro can have an arg list after the their mandatory parameters.
This causes me a problem, because when i call my method with > 2 args, then the 3rd argument is used as the method name, which is wrong.

Comment: The solution i can think of is to hardcode a maximum number of arguments in the macro that returns the actual macro name  (i.e GET_MACRO() in the linked question). This would be done by redirecting to the overload with 2 args until say 32 args. But that seems a little dirty. Would you have an idea on how to handle that more clearly ? Though don't waste your time if it doesn't come to mind easily. Thanks.

Comment: Macros cannot be overloaded, and they cannot count their arguments, whether variadic or not.  You can probably do what you describe with just two macros, one for the 1-arg special case, and the other for 2 or more arguments.  That latter would have the form `MACRO2(arg1, ...)` because the `...` must always correspond to at least one actual argument.