# Comma in C/C++ macro passed to another macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I have these macros which generate error in Visual Studio 2015.

```
#define log_params  __FILE__, __LINE__
#define log(file, line, message, ...) _snprintf_s(nullptr, 0, 0, message,  __VA_ARGS__)
```

Now calling this never works

```
 log(log_params, "testing %d", 4)
```

Any thoughts?
I also checked output of preprocessor and it is:

```
_snprintf_s(nullptr, 0, 0, 4 );
```

**EDIT 1**
Intresting finding

```
#define log(file, line, message, ...) file line
```

will produce this :

```
"service.cpp", 164 "testing %d"
```

Is it normal?

Comment: log is a macro expecting (at least) 4 arguments.

Comment: I'm getting `_snprintf_s(nullptr, 0,0,4, );` which makes sense. Are you sure the output of the preprocessor  was copy/pasted correctly?

Comment: That's not C, but C++.

Comment: @ArifBurhan While a variadic macro with an empty variadic list is forbidden by the standard, it's supported as an extension by most compilers (where an empty variadic list is treated as a list with zero tokens).  [_However_, there's no consensus on how to support this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro#Trailing_comma).  Visual Studio is surprisingly polite, and swallows the comma without requiring special syntax.  GCC uses the syntax `##__VA_ARGS__`, instead of the standard `__VA_ARGS__`, to indicate that the comma should be swallowed in case of zero-token variadic lists.

Comment: I am actually getting   `_snprintf_s(nullptr, 0, 0, 4  ) ` but I am guessing I should get `_snprintf_s(nullptr, 0, 0, "testing $d",4  )`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solved my problem

[__VA_ARGS__ expansion using MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399191/va-args-expansion-using-msvc)

so now I am using

```
 #define EXPAND( x ) x
 #define Log_printf( file_name,line, message,...)  _snprintf_s(nullptr, 0,0,message, __VA_ARGS__)
 #define Log(...) EXPAND (Log_printf(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Answer (score 4):

The following invocation:

```
log(log_params, "testing %d", 4)
```

calls function-like macro `log` with three *actual* arguments. Their replacements are not resolved before arguments are "passed" to the macro. In other words, even if `log_params` contains comma by itself, this comma is not taken into account during function-like macro call resolution.

Thus, you are effectively passing arguments as:

```
file    ---> __FILE__, __LINE__
line    ---> "testing %d"
message ---> 4
```

First two parameters are ignored by the replacement, and eventually you obtain:

```
_snprintf_s(nullptr, 0, 0, 4,  __VA_ARGS__)
```

which in turns become (as MSVC is happy to ignore requirement for at least one variadic argument):

```
_snprintf_s(nullptr, 0, 0, 4)
```