# VC Bug? Compiler Unable to Count __VA_ARGS__' Arguments

Tags: variadic-macros, visual-c++-2015

*Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3* issues errors when compiling the [code below](http://rextester.com/RMRL99968). Looks like a bug to me.

Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

#define A( a, b, c, ... ) #__VA_ARGS__
#define B( ... ) A(__VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
  // warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'A'
  // error C2059: syntax error: ';'
  std::cout << B( 1, 2, 3, 4 ); // should print '4'                                    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [MSVC doesn't expand `__VA_ARGS__` correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly)

Comment: @cpplearner Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me too. It's possible to work around it with another layer of macros:

```
#define EXPAND(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define A( a, b, c, ... ) #__VA_ARGS__
#define B( ... ) EXPAND(EXPAND(A) (__VA_ARGS__))
```

The idea is that first, `EXPAND(A)` gets expanded to `A` and `(__VA_ARGS__)` gets expanded to `( 1, 2, 3, 4 )`. Then, you're left with `A ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )`, which VC++ understands if you force it to expand yet again.

Comment: I guess `#define EXPAND( a ) a` & `#define B( ... ) EXPAND(A(__VA_ARGS__))` is simpler.

Comment: @ZDF You do need `...` and `__VA_ARGS__` for `EXPAND` if you may want to pass it anything containing commas. As for `EXPAND(A(__VA_ARGS__))`, that should still try to expand `A(__VA_ARGS__)` first, and then expand the result again. If that is enough to suppress the warning, I think you've found another bug, and if *that* bug manages to get fixed before the original does, the code will break again.

Comment: I guess I did not find a thing. :) According to Microsoft, the behavior is the right one. See the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly) provided by cpplearner.

Comment: @ZDF Microsoft is wrong on this. They're conveniently ignoring [cpp.subst]p2, "An identiﬁer `__VA_ARGS__` that occurs in the replacement list shall be treated as if it were a parameter, and the variable arguments shall form the preprocessing tokens used to replace it." Note the "as if it were a parameter". The replacement of parameters happens *before* the macro definition is expanded again, and commas contained therein can be used as macro argument separators.

Comment: I have filled a bug form at Microsoft Connect, but I doubt that they will change anything. It wouldn't be the first time. Thank you.