# Passing template parameters into macros in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros, visual-studio-2017, variadic-macros

I am trying to compile C++ code in Visual Studio 2017 that was originally developed on Linux.  The project as is compiles on Linux but not in VS.  The errors come from trying to use a macro to compare template parameters.

Call:

```
EXPECT_MATRIX_EQUAL(filter.xhat, mat);
```

Where 'filter.xhat' and 'mat' are both vectors

Defines:

```
#define EXPECT_MATRIX_EQUAL(...) \
NAVUTILS_TEST_MATRIX_EQUAL_(GTEST_NONFATAL_FAILURE_, __VA_ARGS__)

#define NAVUTILS_TEST_MATRIX_EQUAL_(fail, expected, actual, ...) \
NAVUTILS_TEST_EQUAL_(expected, \
                   actual,   \
                   __matrices_equal(expected, actual, ##__VA_ARGS__), \
                   fail)
#define NAVUTILS_TEST_EQUAL_(expected, actual, testExpr, fail) \
GTEST_TEST_BOOLEAN_(testExpr, #testExpr, actual, expected, fail) \
<< "Value of " #expected " [" << (expected).rows() << " x " << (expected).cols() << "]:\n" \
<< (expected) \
<< "\n\nValue of " #actual " [" << (actual).rows() << " x " << (actual).cols() << "]:\n" \
<< (actual)   \
<< "\n\n"
```

Errors:

```
C:\Users\ANTadmin\Desktop\scorpion-cpp\test\include\LinearFilterTests.h(19): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'NAVUTILS_TEST_MATRIX_EQUAL_' 
C:\Users\ANTadmin\Desktop\scorpion-cpp\test\include\LinearFilterTests.h(19): error C2059: syntax error: ')' 
C:\Users\ANTadmin\Desktop\scorpion-cpp\test\include\LinearFilterTests.h(19): error C2181: illegal else without matching if 
C:\Users\ANTadmin\Desktop\scorpion-cpp\test\include\LinearFilterTests.h(19): error C2065: 'gtest_ar_': undeclared identifier 
C:\Users\ANTadmin\Desktop\scorpion-cpp\test\include\LinearFilterTests.h(19): error C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union 
C:\Users\ANTadmin\Desktop\scorpion-cpp\test\include\LinearFilterTests.h(19): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'testing::internal::AssertHelper' 
C:\Users\ANTadmin\Desktop\scorpion-cpp\test\include\LinearFilterTests.h(19): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

I'm assuming there has to be something special with MSVC with how macros are used that I'm missing.  From what I've researched the overloaded macros should be handled properly so I don't understand why I'm getting these errors.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is the way MSVC handles `__VA_ARGS__` in a macro call inside a macro expansion. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly) and the answer which includes a statement from Microsoft about the interpretation of the standard. The solution, as suggested in the accepted answer to that question, is an extra level of indirection:

```
#define EXPAND_(X) X
#define EXPECT_MATRIX_EQUAL(...) \
EXPAND_(NAVUTILS_TEST_MATRIX_EQUAL_(GTEST_NONFATAL_FAILURE_, __VA_ARGS__))
```

There is also another issue:

```
__matrices_equal(expected, actual, ##__VA_ARGS__), \
```

That use of `##` to avoid including the preceding <kbd>,</kbd> if `__VA_ARGS__` is empty is a GCC extension and should not be used in portable code. However, apparently it works in MSVC.