# Variadic Macro working evaluating correctly with clang but not the windows compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

So I have this macro that takes a varying number of arguments and calls another macro based upon the number of arguments

```cpp
#define VA_NARGS_IMPL(_1, _2, _3, _4, N, ...) BENCHMARK##N
#define VA_NARGS(...)  VA_NARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__, 4, 3, 2, 1)

#define BENCHMARK(...) VA_NARGS(__VA_ARGS__)( __VA_ARGS__ )
```

so `BENCHMARK( T, 1)` becomes `BENCHMARK2(T, 1)` which is ...

```cpp
#define BENCHMARK2( test, description ) \
  BENCHMARK_INTERNAL( test, 0, 0, description ) // NOLINT
```

which becomes (Only providing a snippet) ...

```cpp
#define BENCHMARK_INTERNAL(test, lb, ub, d)                                   \
  struct test : public Test {                                                 \
    public:    ...                                                            \
```

Clang is evaluating the MACROS as I would expect, here is a snippet from that expansion ...

```cpp
struct T : public Test { public: ...
```

but when windows preprocesses this file I get ...

```cpp
struct T, 1 : public Test { public: ...
```

However, if I directly call BENCHMARK2 ... `BENCHMARK2( T, 1)` everything works as I would expect.

Does windows handle variadic macros differently? Is there a cross platform solution for my scenario?

I'm using MSVC's x64 compiler (version 14.28.29333)

Comment: Something's wrong with your problem description -- I don't see `VA_NARGS` defined, nor `BENCHMARK2` called.

Comment: `VA_NARGS(__VA_ARGS__)` becomes BENCHMARK2. I added VA_NARGS for context

Comment: Which compiler is the Windows compiler?  I'm presently working with 3 compilers running on Windows.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The full path to the compiler I'm using is  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe` If there's anything outside of the binary/version/architecture I can offer up to provide context please let me know.

Comment: With MSVC, `VA_NARGS(T, 1)` becomes `BENCHMARK1`, not `BENCHMARK2`: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jEbEbTEo6).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) I found the solution.

My question was similar to this post - [MSVC doesn't expand __VA_ARGS__ correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly)

The issue was `VA_NARGS` not expanding correctly on windows. I fixed it by adding this compilation flag `/Zc:preprocessor` .