# what's difference between passing __VA_ARGS__ and ##__VA_ARGS__ between macro

Tags: c++, macros

This is my macro define，I want to make a simple reflection of the struct/class members

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ReflectionTypeStringTraits {
    static const char* value;
};

template <>
struct ReflectionTypeStringTraits<int> {
    static const char* value;
};
const char* ReflectionTypeStringTraits<int>::value = "int";

template <>
struct ReflectionTypeStringTraits<std::string> {
    static const char* value;
};
const char* ReflectionTypeStringTraits<std::string>::value = "string";

#define REFLECTION_MACRO_CALL_VEC(CALL1, CALL2, CALL3, CALL4, CALL, ...) CALL

#define REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_0(struct_name)
#define REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_1(struct_name, member_name) { #member_name, ReflectionTypeStringTraits<decltype(struct_name::member_name)>::value },
#define REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_2(struct_name, member_name, ...)  REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_1(struct_name, member_name) REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_1(struct_name,  ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_3(struct_name, member_name, ...) REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_1(struct_name, member_name) REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_2(struct_name,  ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_4(struct_name, member_name, ...) REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_1(struct_name, member_name) REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_3(struct_name,  ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP(struct_name, ...) \
    REFLECTION_MACRO_CALL_VEC(__VA_ARGS__, \
    REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_4, REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_3, REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_2, REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_1, \
    REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_0)(struct_name, __VA_ARGS__)


#define MAKE_REFLECTION(struct_name, ...) \
struct struct_name##_Reflection { \
    struct_name##_Reflection(struct_name& obj) : this_(std::make_shared<struct_name>(obj)) {} \
    std::shared_ptr<struct_name> this_; \
    static std::map<std::string, std::string> fieldMap; \
}; \
std::map<std::string, std::string> struct_name##_Reflection::fieldMap = { \
    REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP(struct_name, __VA_ARGS__) \
}

#define GET_REFLECTION(struct_name, obj) struct_name##_Reflection(obj)
```

This is my test

```cpp
struct Test {
    int a;
    int b;
    std::string c;
};

MAKE_REFLECTION(Test, a, b, c);
```

The macro is expand to

```cpp
struct Test_Reflection {
    Test_Reflection(Test& obj) : this_(std::make_shared<Test>(obj)) {} 
    std::shared_ptr<Test> this_; 
    static std::map<std::string, std::string> fieldMap;
};
std::map<std::string, std::string> Test_Reflection::fieldMap = { 
    { "a,b,c", ReflectionTypeStringTraits<decltype(Test::a,b,c)>::value }, 
};
```

But what I want is

```cpp
struct Test_Reflection {
    Test_Reflection(Test& obj) : this_(std::make_shared<Test>(obj)) {} 
    std::shared_ptr<Test> this_; 
    static std::map<std::string, std::string> fieldMap;
};
std::map<std::string, std::string> Test_Reflection::fieldMap = { 
    { "a", ReflectionTypeStringTraits<decltype(Test::a)>::value }, 
    { "b", ReflectionTypeStringTraits<decltype(Test::b)>::value }, 
    { "c", ReflectionTypeStringTraits<decltype(Test::c)>::value }, 
};
```

If I call REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_3 directly, It will get correct expand

```cpp
REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_3(Test, a, b, c);
/* expand success
{ "a", ReflectionTypeStringTraits<decltype(Test::a)>::value }, 
{ "b", ReflectionTypeStringTraits<decltype(Test::b)>::value }, 
{ "c", ReflectionTypeStringTraits<decltype(Test::c)>::value }, ;
*/
```

If I remove the *##* of **VA_ARGS** in REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_N, the macro parameter will become one

```cpp
#define REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_0(struct_name)
#define REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_1(struct_name, member_name) { #member_name, ReflectionTypeStringTraits<decltype(struct_name::member_name)>::value },
#define REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_2(struct_name, member_name, ...)  REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_1(struct_name, member_name) REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_1(struct_name,  __VA_ARGS__)
#define REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_3(struct_name, member_name, ...) REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_1(struct_name, member_name) REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_2(struct_name,  __VA_ARGS__)
#define REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_4(struct_name, member_name, ...) REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_1(struct_name, member_name) REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_3(struct_name,  __VA_ARGS__)

// after change the ##__VA_ARGS__ to __VA_ARGS__
REFLECTION_TYPE_MEMBER_TYPE_MAP_3(Test, a, b, c);
/* only first parameter is correct
{ "a", ReflectionTypeStringTraits<decltype(Test::a)>::value }, 
{ "b, c", ReflectionTypeStringTraits<decltype(Test::b, c)>::value }, 
{ , ReflectionTypeStringTraits<decltype(Test::)>::value }, ;
*/
```

Comment: [this answer works for me without change compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default MSVC preprocessor is just buggy. Adding `/Zc:preprocessor` to switch to the modern preprocessor fixes the issue.

GCC and Clang do the right thing without any flags in this case.

---

I don't think learning to accomodate the legacy preprocessor is worth one's time.

You can add following check to explicitly detect the legacy preprocessor and avoid the obscure errors if you forget to enable the modern one:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && !defined(__clang__) && (!defined(_MSVC_TRADITIONAL) || _MSVC_TRADITIONAL == 1)
#error The standard-conformant MSVC preprocessor is required, enable it with `/Zc:preprocessor`.
#endif
```

Comment: I can't find /Zc:preprocessor this setting in vs2013, is there any way to fix the issue?

Comment: @kevin Why are you not using VS 2022?

Comment: old project, you know......

Comment: @kevin I would push for an upgrade. It's certainly possible to work around the quirky preprocessor, but it's not something I'd want to waste my time on.