C++ preprocessor macro with and without arguments
I would like to call two different macros based on whether the macro invocation was with or without parameters. Based on the many examples on SO regarding specific numbers of parameters, I came up with this, but it is not expanding __VA_OPT__(_WITH_ARGS):
#define FUN() "call without arguments"
#define FUN_WITH_ARGS(...) "call with arguments"
#define GET_MACRO(b) FUN##b
#define CALL(...) GET_MACRO(__VA_OPT__(_WITH_ARGS))(__VA_ARGS__)

CALL() // --> "call without arguments"
CALL(5) // --> "call with arguments"

How can I expand __VA_OPT__(_WITH_ARGS) so that CALL calls either FUN or FUN_WITH_ARGS?
Edit: fixed typos - still not working in MSVC.

You're using the wrong tool for the job.  Macros are very primitive, even if you get it to work it's going to be brittle.

What are you trying to accomplish with this?  It's pretty trivial to do this with functions now.  for instance template <typename... Args> void call(Args&&...) { if constexpr (sizeof... Args == 0) "call without arguments"; else "call with arguments"; }

You have tagged question as C++. Macros are C feature and in C++ should be avoided as much as possible. Since C++20 the cases where macros are a necessity are almost none existent. Please explain why you think you need this macros.

Did you mean __VA_OPT__ or __VA_ARGS__?

what Yksisarvinen says. If you use the right macros it works as expected https://godbolt.org/z/nE6b8bKee. Voting to close as typo

If you must use macros, give them different names.

On MSVC you need /std:c++latest /Zc:preprocessor (or c++20 instead of c++latest).

Overloading on number of macro arguments is a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21371401/9072753 . To make it work under msvc, you need compiler options, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly .

IMO question suffers from XY problem. I do not get it why not simple overload is bad in this case.

Seems to work, what is the issue? https://godbolt.org/z/zxMfvorMs

@KamilCuk that first "duplicate" in on 2 vs. 3 parameters - I want {0} vs {1, 2, 3, 4, ...} parameters, so it's not exactly a duplicate. @HolyBlackCat nailed it with /Zc:preprocessor - thanks!

@MarekR "Macros [...] in C++ should be avoided as much as possible" - and yet they introduced __VA_OPT__ in C++20 ...
