MSVC doesn't seem to resolve recursive macros the same way GCC does
I have the following recursive macro:
#define MAP_OUT
#define A(x) x B MAP_OUT (x)
#define B(x) x A MAP_OUT (x)

#define EVAL0(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EVAL4(...) EVAL0 (EVAL0 (EVAL0 (__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL(...)  EVAL4 (EVAL4 (EVAL4 (__VA_ARGS__)))

EVAL(A(blah));

When I compile the code with GCC v11.4.0, I get the following output which is what I expect:
> gcc -E example.c
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah A (blah);

However, for some reason when I compile it with current latest version of Visual Studio 2022's compiler on  the command line C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.41.34120 I get the following output which is the wrong expansion of the macro:
> cl /P example.c
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah B  (blah);

Perhaps I'm wrong and this is not an issue with Visual Studio and could have something to do with the standard not being specific about how to resolve nested macros in this situation. Anyhow, is there a way for me to make Visual Studio replicate the behavior of GCC in this macro expansion, through a compiler flag maybe?
I've looked through the the Visual Studio Compiler command line options to see if there was a setting to change the behavior of how the preprocessor expands nested variadic macros. I thought I had when I saw the /Zc flag in the documentation, however after trying a lot of them I still couldn't get the same output the GCC preprocessor was generating.

You are correct: the way __VA_ARGS__ works in MS’s CPP is different than with GCC’s CPP — they are different programs and you are looking for behavior that is implementation-specific. Alas, I do not know enough to give you a quick&correct answer on how to fix it other than “you must target each system separately”.

Not exactly, @Dúthomhas. Yes, by default, MSVC behaves differently than GCC does with respect to __VA_ARGS__, and in that sense the behavior is implementation specific. But this is not an area where the C language actually gives implementations latitude to differ.  A better description, then, is that the behavior of MSVC's traditional C preprocessor is buggy in this area.  This is in fact a fairly well-known MSVC bug.

@JohnBollinger MS does not consider it a bug, and MSVC is never going to change its behavior with respect to this, no matter what the C committee says. It is a de facto implementation-specific issue, since before the standards were written to prefer GCC. Either way, we must treat them separately to solve the issue.

@JohnBollinger: Unfortunately not a bug. A bug is a deviation from specification. Microsoft does not, to my knowledge, specify MSVC conforms to the C standard. This should be a reminder that the C standard is voluntary and is not a default one can expect a compiler to conform to.

@Dúthomhas, Microsoft describes the "experimental preprocessor" that fixes this behavior as "improv[ing] standards conformance, fix[ing] longstanding bugs, and chang[ing] some behaviors that are officially undefined".  Unless you're prepared to claim that MS thinks this behavior is undefined, then they do accept it at least as non-conforming.

@Dúthomhas, It's unclear whether MS will ever switch to defaulting to their more conformant preprocessor, but even today you can choose that behavior (see dupe target) in order to avoid treating these compilers differently with respect to this issue.

@EricPostpischil, as I know we've discussed before, I consider your definition of "bug" too narrow.

@JohnBollinger: What objective definition do you have?

@JohnBollinger I think you have a biased slant on this. MS knows full well that their CPP does not conform to the current C standards — they don’t care. They’ll maintain consistent, non-breaking behavior for as long as there is a significant (== paying) code base expecting them to maintain it. Sure, you can ask people to modify their major toolchains to compile your code... or you could just write code that works with it.

@Dúthomhas, I have an opinionated slant.  Specifically, it is my opinion that a company that sells a product that they claim provides a C compiler and runtime library should make every effort to ensure that it complies with the international standard that defines what that is.  Some version of it, at least.  To the extent that such a company both (i) fails to do so, and (ii) denies that those failures constitute product flaws, I characterize that as a deceptive business practice.  I understand MS's business reasons for doing so, but that does not make its behavior good or acceptable.

@JohnBollinger You have a valid opinion. Alas, MS only claims to provide a C++ compiler, one that can also frob most C. Further, MS’s compiler options are older than the C standards. You may consider it inexcusable that they are a standard unto themselves, but, it is what it is.

I don't know about "inexcusable", @Dúthomhas, but I do consider the situation to justify calling the MS C compiler's non-conformance issues to constitute bugs.  Whether MS also considers them bugs -- and it's not clear that they don't -- is immaterial.

@EricPostpischil, who says that the definition has to be objective?  Merriam Webster's definition matches my own usage of the word pretty well: "an unexpected defect, fault, flaw, or imperfection". In my experience, it is not so uncommon for people to disagree about whether a particular software characteristic constitutes a bug, so Merriam Webster and I must not be the only people to use a definition more subjective than yours.

@JohnBollinger I consider this whole conversation to be walking around the important point: MSVC behaves differently and thus must be programmed differently. Whether or not that is a right state of things is immaterial.

@JohnBollinger: If it is not objective, it is not engineering. Sure, people may use the word “bug” in another opinion-based sense in common discourse. That does not make it a suitable definition for software engineering. If you want to call MSVC’s behavior a shortcoming, fine. But, if it behaves as Microsoft intended, it is not a software engineering bug.

Thank you, @EricPostpischil.  In that case, when, in the future, you observe me to use the word "bug" in a manner that does not conform to your strict definition, please assume that I mean it in a common discourse sense.  You might consider extending the same courtesy to others, as well.

Adding /experimental:preprocesor seemed to do the trick (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly)
